# Gulp file not updating/building css in browser

Tags: javascript, gulp

So I can compile scss to css fine.

However, whenever I change anything in my scss file it has no effect on the page unless I build styles.

My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');

// Gulp watches
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); // Sass watch
  // gulp.watch('dist/css/main.css');
});

// Sass compiler
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass()) // Convert Sass to CSS
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

// Compile css files
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

/** Default builds **/

// Build
gulp.task('build', ['styles']);

// Watch and build changes
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch']);
```

My index.html file linked to my dist css file is this correct also?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/main.css">
```

All that keeps happening is I gulp watch files okay but if I change anything (something simple like body background colour) nothing happens. Not even on hard refresh. I have to gulp build styles. I am new to gulp/learning but surely building styles after every change cannot be right?

Thank you for any suggestions. I know I asked about compiling, I worked out why that wasn't working, but I've been going around in circles with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is that the watch task of gulp is only compiling the css from sass, but not concatenating the css in `dist/css/main.css`.

Add the task `styles` to the watch method of gulp and try again:

```
// Gulp watches
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass', 'styles']); // Sass watch
});
```

Hope this helps! :)